# MySQL stored procedure variable issue

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedures

Variable never got updated with query, and always have default values

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE sP INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE cBB INT DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT sprice, cb INTO  sP, cBB FROM item WHERE id = 2;
END
```

Need a little guidance here for whats wrong with it (MySQL version 5.5.20)

Comment: Why not `SELECT sP AS sprice, cB AS cb FROM item WHERE id = 2;` directly? Why do you need this variables inside this procedure?

Comment: variables should also work (maybe he will use them later in another query in procedure). Are you sure SELECT sprice, cb FROM item WHERE id = 2 return any value?

Comment: it returns values, even work well if i use `INTO @varname` but some issue with the above mentioned way

Comment: If names are different from db fields (like Devart suggested) then something with fetching query is wrong. Can you setup [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85567 i didnt get how to add my procedure in there. hope you got the idea from the above post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following two methods works well and no need to DECLARE variable

```
BEGIN
     SELECT @sP := sprice, @cBB := cb FROM item WHERE id = 2;
END
```

Or if we want to do it with `INTO` clause

```
BEGIN
     SELECT sprice, cb INTO  @sP, @cBB FROM item WHERE id = 2;
END
```

Difference is that in first statement you can have columns which don't need to be stored in variable while in second one `... INTO ...` every listed column must be stored in variable.

Answer (score 1):

Rename the variable `cb` to another one -

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE sP INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE cB_var INT DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT sprice, cb INTO  sP, cB_var FROM item WHERE id = 2;
END
```

Variable names should differ from field names.

Comment: Var names are symbolic but anyway i changed it in the main post to avoid confusion thanks for your suggestion